# R How to turn off specific error

Tags: r, error-handling

How can you globally turn off a specific error in R?

For example, I want to "globally" ignore the common error in Rstudio:
"Error in plot.new() : figure margins too large"  without changing every plot call and without making the plot panel large in Rstudio.

E.g., in Matlab doing so is possible, I think. How to do so in R? Thanks!

Comment: (1) I don't think this is possible; (2) I'm not sure what you want to have happen here.  Do you want R to draw the plot despite the fact that the figure margins are too large?  An error in R (as opposed to a warning) typically means that R has encountered an issue that it can't (or won't) get past.  Sometimes there are options or arguments that can override the error, but often not.

Comment: I would like R to continue despite the error so to say. For example the plot is not drawn and the R-script is continued.

Comment: oh, OK, that makes more sense.

Comment: See also `?try` and `?tryCatch` that allow to deal with errors and conditions. For instance, you can enclose the line which are giving the error with `try` and the script will continue to execute, even if an error occurred.

Comment: @nicola: Ok, but then you have to change every, e.g., plot, call in the R-script to enclose it by try or tryCatch and doing so would ignore all errors and not just a specific one.

Comment: For this specific example: Just don't plot to the RStudio device. Open your own graphics device, which allows you to specify dimensions, and plot to that device. Typically, you would plot to a file.

Comment: @Roland Thanks for this suggestion. For the specific example, you can put " dev.new() " at the beginning of your R-script to open a "detached" graphics device.

Answer (score 0):

Check this. This is the error.

```
stop("Urgh, the iphone is in the blender !")
```

And this is the solution using try catch.

```
tryCatch({
   stop("Urgh, the iphone is in the blender !")
}, error=function(e){})
```

Comment: Okay, thanks. Is it possible to turn off only one specific error?

Comment: @anindya It's a local and non-specific solution, right? So this is probably the only possibility (?) but not what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

The above solutions already mention `suppresX`-solutions and `tryCatch`. `dplyr` has a nice wrapper for `tryCatch` called `failwith`:

```
library(dplyr)
toyfun <- function(x){
  stopifnot(x=="coffee")
  return(":)")
}
toyfun(42) # gives error message
toyfun <- failwith(":(", toyfun, quiet=T)
toyfun(42)
[1] ":("
```

In your concrete example, you can overwrite the problematic function. Note that this is dangerous and you should only use it if it really bothers you.

```
plot <- failwith(warning("sth wrong"), plot, quiet=T)
```

or alternatively:

```
plot <- function(...) tryCatch(plot(...), error=function(e){})
```

In this way, you have a manipulated function called `plot` in the workspace, which gets called instead of `base::plot`. I think this is as "global" a solution as you'll get. A much safer route, however, would be to name that function differently, and to change the function calls in your code accordingly.

Comment: Thanks. Is it possible to turn off only one specific error? 
If you use `plot <- failwith(warning("sth wrong"), plot, quiet=T)` it will use the failwith case for every error, right? (May be this is the only possible solution?!)

Comment: I am not aware of that, unless you use the `tryCatch` solution outlined by others, where you define a custom function yourself that deals with the error. I think the simplest and best way to turn off a specific error is to change your code so that you actually avoid the error.

Answer (score -1):

I think you are looking for `suppressWarnings(plot(...))` or if it is a message `suppressMessages(plot(...))`.

Comment: Yes, it does not work for errors. So may be the only way is to use try or tryCatch as Nicola and Roland suggested. Thanks.